# Allegro and Qt creator - how to set up this two?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, allegro

I've looked for it for a long time and I couldn't find it, so could anybody tell me how to set up allegro (4.2.3) with qt creator (2.3.0), Qt 4.7.4 ?

Thanks in advance,
Martin.

EDIT:

OK, by accident, I finally managed to add some of the allegro features into qt creator :p
I added:

`INCLUDEPATH += "path_to_allegro-4.4.2-mingw-4.4.0/include"`

`LIBS +="path_to_allegro-4.4.2-mingw-4.4.0/lib/liballegro-4.4.2-md.a"`

When everything seemed to build and so on, some sh** apeared -.-

(C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator_process_stub.exe) saying: `Naci`.

as simply as I can -- WTF?